# Using VBA, how can I select multiple rows, on multiple worksheets for printing?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that contains multiple worksheets.  I need to select all rows, in certain worksheets, so that I can print all rows, across all selected worksheets, to a single document.

The following code is used to select all pertinent worksheets and rows that are to be printed.  This code works until I attempt to select rows from a second worksheet.

```
Dim no_selected_worksheets As Boolean
no_selected_worksheets = True

Dim list_choose As Long
For list_choose = 0 To FormsToPrint.ListCount - 1
    If FormsToPrint.Selected(list_choose) Then
        With Worksheets(list_choose + 2)
            If no_selected_worksheets Then
                .Select      'This works.
                .Rows.Select 'So does this.
                no_selected_worksheets = False
            Else
                .Select (False) 'This works too..
                .Rows.Select    ' but here, VBA reports the error:
                                ' "Select Method of Range class failed"
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next
```

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Have you tried setting the print area on each sheet, instead of printing the selected rows?

Comment: try to add `.Activate` before the line of code you have a problem with... In other words, you need to have this sheet activated before you attempt to select any rows in it.

Comment: @TimWilliams.  No.  I'll admit, though I can use Excel to analyze numbers, this spreadsheet is doing far more than I would have ever implemented.  Would you mind posting an answer, with code, showing how to correctly set the print area in VBA?

Comment: @KazJaw, I added the activate statement.  This bug goes away, however, I have another problem.  All worksheets are being printed.  I know this may seem stupid, but my knowledge comes from reading a lot of conflicting help, and no solution that I've found has actually worked.  This is the closest I've managed to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim i As Long
Dim list_choose As Long

    For list_choose = 0 To FormsToPrint.ListCount - 1
        i = i + 1
        If FormsToPrint.Selected(list_choose) Then
            With Worksheets(list_choose + 2)
                .Select (i = 1)
                'EDIT below
                .PageSetup.PrintArea = .UsedRange.Address(false,false)
            End With
        End If
    Next

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim, I did try to solve this one on my own.  The Worksheet class doesn't appear to have a `PrintArea` property.  If I move the ".", so that I'm accessing the global, PrintArea object, it ends up printing only the last worksheet that is selected in the list.  Is the `PrintArea` object buried somewhere else in the Worksheet?  I can't find it in the Object Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to use `.select` on a range is to have the worksheet "active". This should answer your question, but I think you've complicated things for yourself.

```
.
.
Else
    .Activate       ' new line
    .Select (False) 
    .Rows.Select
End If
.
.
```

In Excel macros, I try to avoid using .select and instead refer to ranges directly. For instance if I want to copy values from one range to another it would be something like:

```
Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

Also, looks like you're looping through the sheets by index number, starting at the second one until you get to ListCount. Be aware that the sheet index changes based on tab order. You may be better off looping through all worksheets in the workbook with a "For Each" loop and comparing each sheet's name to a white or black list.